# How to join parent and child tables to get the following using SQL or HQL

Tags: sql, hql

Given Table1 and Table2 as below how to return the resultset shown below?

TABLE1

```
TBL1_PK     TBL1_COL2
1            A
```

TABLE2

```
TBL2_PK  TABLE1_FK    ROLE_CD           FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
1      1           ROLE_1       DEF   GHI
2      1           ROLE_2       JKL   MNP
3      1           ROLE_3       RST   UVW
```

RESULSET

```
TBL1_COL2  ROLE_1_FIRST_NAME ROLE1_LAST_NAME ROLE_2_FIRST_NAME ROLE_2_LAST_NAME
A          DEF               GHI             JKL               MNP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join table 1 to table 2 twice with 2 different aliases.  Then restrict the aliases as needed to get role_1 from one and role_2 from the other

```
select
 T1.TBL1_COL2 as "TBL1_COL2",
 T2R1.FIRST_NAME as "Role_1_first_name",
 T2R1.Last_name as "Role_1_last_name",
 T2R2.First_name as "Role_2_first_name",
 T2R2.Last_name as "Role_2_last_name"
from 
   Table1 as T1
 inner join Table2 as T2R1 on T1.TBL1_PK = T2R1.Table1_fk
 inner join Table2 as T2R2 on T2.TBL1_PK = T2T2.Table1_fk
where
    T2R1.role_cd = "Role_1"
and T2T2.role_cd = "Role_2";
```

Comment: Mike's approach worked for me. Thanks everyone.                        select
 T1.TBL1_COL2 as "TBL1_COL2",
 T2R1.FIRST_NAME as "ROLE_1_FIRST_NAME"
 T2R1.LAST_NAME as "ROLE_1_LAST_NAME",
 T2R2.FIRST_NAME as "ROLE_2_FIRST_NAME",
 T2R2.LAST_NAME as "ROLE_2_LAST_NAME"
from 
   Table1 as T1
 inner join Table2 as T2R1 on T1.TBL1_PK = T2R1.TABLE1_FK
 inner join Table2 as T2R2 on T1.TBL1_PK = T2T2.TABLE1_FK
where
    T2R1.role_cd = 'ROLE_1'
and T2R2.role_cd = 'ROLE_2'

Comment: This is an inefficient approach. The second table is read twice. You don't need to read it twice

Comment: The efficiency depends on a lot of things.  Any optimizer will read the table from disk only once.  If the whole table is cached in memory there may be no disk reads at all.  After that, the question becomes whether 4 case statements and an aggregation is faster than an additional primary key lookup and 2 equality comparisons.  I'll bet, as usual, the answer is "it depends".  If this is a mission critical query where time and CPU is important, then I would suggest testing both.  If not, I suggest running whichever is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Oh and remember that for an aggregation, no rows come back until the whole query is done and held in memory.  This will lead to a slower first record response time.  It also means that the result table will need to be in memory as well as the 2 input tables.  The method above can spill the results back to the client as they are built. Network transfer rates will probably still mean that the whole output table will be in memory, but if it were used as a sub-query that could immediately consume the rows in parallel, then the above could be much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to do this:

```
select t1.TBL1_COL2,
    max(case 
            when t2.role_cd = 'ROLE_1'
                then t2.first_name
            end) ROLE_1_FIRST_NAME,
    max(case 
            when t2.role_cd = 'ROLE_1'
                then t2.last_name
            end) ROLE1_LAST_NAME,
    max(case 
            when t2.role_cd = 'ROLE_2'
                then t2.first_name
            end) ROLE_2_FIRST_NAME,
    max(case 
            when t2.role_cd = 'ROLE_2'
                then t2.last_name
            end) ROLE2_LAST_NAME
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.tbl1_pk = t2.table1_fk
group by t1.TBL1_COL2
```